# Unexpected token . in JSON at position 3 when making a POST HTTP Call in Angular

Tags: json, angular, angular-http

I'm attempting to parse a single string response to JSON, but I'm getting an error.

> Unexpected token . in JSON at position 3

The string I'm trying to parse is simply

```
1.0.INDIVIDUAL
```

I thought that full stops were allowed in JSON strings? Unless there's an additional step I'm missing?

When I make the same call to the API in Postman I get the expected response.

[image: r]

However when I send just the string over (not parsed) I get a 415 Media Unsupported response from the API server.

Comment: that is weird, how are you parsing it?

Comment: Just wrap it in quotes..

Answer (score -1):

A string is not valid JSON to pass as a parameter `JSON.parse`.  You will need to put it in quotes, or another object and return it from the server.

```js
try {
  JSON.parse('STRING');
} catch(e) {
  console.log('not valid', e)
}

// valid quoted string
console.log(JSON.parse('"STRING"'));

// valid object
console.log(JSON.parse('{"data": "STRING"}'));
```

Comment: That is actually not correct, you can pass a string to the function it just need to be a valid string, i.e between `""` (or `''`). In your example it should be `JSON.parse('"STRING"')`.

Comment: Good point.  What he is getting now is invalid still.  I'll update the response

Comment: Parsing the JSON is stripping the quotes out though so I still get the Unsupported media response